# GNOME 3 privacy settings in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: gnome, system-settings

Is it possible to change the GNOME 3 privacy settings in Ubuntu Raring? What I am missing is, for example, the configuration for the lock screen notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed change the privacy settings in Gnome3.
Firstly open system-settings click on Privacy and then click Screen Lock.

[image: System-Settings]

You can also change the settings using dconf-editor
Open dconf-editor and navigate through org-gnome-desktop-notifications.

[image: Dconf-Editor]

Comment: The privacy options seems to be missing, see for example: http://imgur.com/WWjeXjN

Comment: Are you using the ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 and ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging ppa's? there is an up to date gnome-control-center in the ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging. Ubuntu ships with the gnome 3.6 and these ppa's bring the gnome 3.8.

Comment: I am using ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 but not ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging. Good to hear an update will be coming down the pipeline. Thanks.